# Dropwizard - How to configure the frequency of archiving?

Tags: logging, dropwizard

I have the following config

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /var/log/myapplication.log
      threshold: ALL
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/myapplication-%d.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
      logFormat: # TODO
```

and I am looking at this documentation 
http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#logging

How can I set the archive frequency to be weekly or daily? Or does this need to be done outside of dropwizard framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropwizard uses Logback internally for logging.
For weekly rotation of logs, you can set the following property in your yaml configuration:

```
archivedLogFilenamePattern: /wombat/foo.%d{yyyy-ww}.log
```

With the %d token specifier, one can include an optional time and date pattern. If it is absent, it is assumed to be yyyy-MM-dd and the logs are rolled daily. Here, yyyy-ww indicates the weekly frequency. Similarly, one can make use of HH, mm to rotate logs hourly or every minute depending upon the use case. One can use any of date and time pattern as specified by the *java.text.SimpleDateFormat* class.

PS: You can find more information [Logback documentation | Time Based Rolling Policy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)

Comment: what in the pattern indicates that its weekly?

Comment: @user_mda updated my answer to include a brief explanation.

Comment: Thank you! That really helps